# C#.net Console Application SQLCommand.CommandTimeOut property not working

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, console-application, connection-timeout

I have a console application written in C# 4.0. I am running a SQL stored procedure that sometimes takes too long and and a connection timeout exception gets thrown.

To handle it, I first set Timeout to 360 in the connection string in the web.config file but no luck.

Then i tried:

```
SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand();
 cmd.CommandTimeout = 360;
```

but this is also not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried to do same with the Entity Framework 4.0 but had the same issue. The timeout value i am providing is not being applied!

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="SERVER=db.mydomain.com;DATABASE=DatabaseName;UID=userID;PWD=Password;Connect Timeout=360;Packet Size=8192;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=1;Max Pool Size=1000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Exception:

```
Timeout expired: The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Comment: So, you want a 6-minute timeout, and it's still timing out at the default 30 seconds?

Comment: I think you are getting confused with command.CommandTimeout and connection timeout. In your web config u have specified connect timeout to 360

Comment: @praveen I see what you are trying to tell me. I am trying both I have added my exception message on top , please take a look

Comment: Try removing connection timeout from your web.config file and use only CommandTimeout in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `CommandTimeout = 0` in your code and remove it from the config file.

Setting the `Timeout = 0` means, it will complete the job in case of long operation also.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `context connection=true` in the connection string in your `Web.config` file?  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATA.SQLCLIENT.SQLCOMMAND.COMMANDTIMEOUT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

> CommandTimeout has no effect when the command is executed against a context connection

Comment: I have added my coonectionstring, please take a look

Comment: Your connection string looks fine to me so that can't be the problem.